# How do you retire an APK?

Tags: google-play

I can't upload a new version of an APK to Google Play because it would supersede an existing version.

So, how do I retire an existing APK so I can upload a new one?

This is the error message that I get...

[image]

So, I have to remove version four. But how? The only option I can see to do this is to manually upload the APK to the console at the same time as deactivating the old. In which case, what's the point of the app publisher?

Comment: The default behavior on the Google Play Store should be to remove the immediately previous version.  What are you currently seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Play console you create a release [as described here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469).

In it there are 3 options:

- APKs to add
- APKs to deactivate
- APKs to release

By default your old APK is in the "APKs to deactivate", which is what you refer to as "retire". If it is giving you this warning it is probably that you have decided to retain it.

The purpose of this is to allow a more complicated "Multi-APK" configuration, where you have different APKs supporting different users, eg one for older phones and one for newer phones. If you don't need it, just put your old APK to be de-activated.

In particular ([from the docs here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011))

In the "Apps to retain" section,

> view details about app bundles or APKs from your previous release that will continue to be served to users.
>
> Clicking ***Deactivate*** moves an artifact to the list of app bundles or APKs that will no longer be served to users.

In the "apps to deactivate" section,

> In this section, view details about app bundles or APKs from your previous release that will no longer be served to users.
>
> Clicking ***Retain*** moves an artifact to the list of app bundles or APKs that will continue to be served to users.

It sounds like you need to click ***Deactivate*** by one of the apps in your retain section.

Comment: How? I can see that I can create a new release and manually upload the APK, but I've been using the app publisher from Xamarin Studio. Surely this doesn't only work the first time that an app is published?

Comment: It sounds like it is using App Publisher in Xamarin Studio that doesn't work for you. Maybe you should ask a question about Xamarin Studio. When you upload an APK manually the previous APK is automatically moved to the "APKs to deactivate" every time, not just the first time (for the first time there is nothing to deactivate). All  the documentation on managing your release, including deactivating and retaining APKs is here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011

Comment: I've added more detailed instructions and more links to the documentation

Comment: Thanks. I won't use Xamarin Studio publisher. Is it normal for Android developers to manually upload an APK?

Comment: Some people manually upload. Some people use the API (I've never used Xamarin Studio Publisher but I assume that's what it does). The API: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing